# How to prevent copying additional nonvisible text

Tags: bash, firefox, clipboard, firefox-extensions

I've asked similiar question [How to make copying command from website to terminal secure?](https://superuser.com/questions/999767/how-to-make-copying-command-from-website-to-terminal-secure).

Scenario is very simple, you want to copy something from website but what you end up with something else.

[Live demo copy text](http://jsfiddle.net/v2ypLt57/)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            -- many, many lines of code

            -- many, lines of code
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

At first glance everything is ok, user understand each line of code and nothing can surprise him, but when he copy/paste it to his favorite `IDE/text editor` he ends with:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            -- many, many lines of code

            any code for example start deleting user data

            -- many, lines of code
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

As you see there is additional payload. It is very easy to overlook it. The same is applicable to commands/bash scripts/sample code/git location repository.

I know answers that state:

- always use trusted source
- retype manually
- always check anything you've copied

The point is that **`what you see is not what you get`**. The best solution whould be some kind of firefox extension/system clipboard utility that will warn/delete invisible text.

It is even possible to achieve this automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Try Firefox extension named [Blank Your Monitor + Easy Reading](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/blank-your-monitor-easy-readin/) (BYM)

To test BYM,

Install the extension.

Then, because jsfiddle frame gets in the way we have to remove it if you want to test this with your jsfiddle demo:

1. https://jsfiddle.net/v2ypLt57/embedded/result/
2. right mouse button
3. This frame
4. Show only this frame

There should no longer be a jsfiddle frame `Result ...` at the top now.

Once you are here then you can test:

### All text

Press the keyboard shortcut: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd>

It asks you:

> Easy Read
>
> No text selected
>
> Do you want to select all text?

OK

Result: New tab is opened, which does uncover the `any code ...`

### some text

You can also have BYM act on a specific segment of code.

For example you select from:

```
        -- many, many lines of code
```

To:

```
        -- many, lines of code
```

Press the keyboard shortcut: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd>

Result:

```
-- many, many lines of code
any code for example start deleting user data
-- many, lines of code
```

As you see it revealed the normally hidden code `any code for ...`

### Bugs

Not sure why but the result loses indentation, probably by design since this is meant for reading long passages of text such as a book, rather than indented programming languages. Maybe you could email the extension author about it.